# Персонаж толкает другие обьекты, хотя не должен

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-code

я начинающий гейм разработчик. Я столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть сцена на которой
есть обьекты: персонаж(на нем висит камера и его текстура), нижний пол и барьеры которые стоят по краям(барьеры и пол обьеденены в один обьект).
На персонаже конечно-же есть скрипт ходьбы, RigitBody2D,BoxCollider2D;
И вот в чем проблема:
Когда персонаж подходит к стене он начинает ее двигать в сторону своего передвижения

Я даже для стен написал отдельный скрипт:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class WallBug : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        position.x = 0;
        position.y = 0;
        position.z = 0;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

Который каждый кадр обнуляет их позицию

Но ничего не помогает(((

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;
    private SpriteRenderer spriterenderer;
    private Animator animator;
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        position.x += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;

        transform.position = position;

        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0f)
            {
                spriterenderer.flipX = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0f)
                {
                    spriterenderer.flipX = false;
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

если что вот код передвижения игрока
Отзовитесь мудрецы которые помогут мне исправить этот баг

Comment: Убрать RigitBody2D у стены?

Comment: На стене висит только milemap collider и скрипт

Comment: Если RigitBody2D нет - объект толкаться не может. Может это персонаж выталкивается из стены? Если камера к персонажу привязана, визуально будет выглядеть как ты описал. Вообще странно двигать персонажа через прямое изменение transform.position, если на нём есть RigidBody2D. Если используется RigidBody2D, то надо через физику двигать, вызывая AddForce и подобное. _ПС: Есть смысл использовать готовое решение, если не понимаешь как сделать контроллер самому._